# Facing this error while run the code below for YOLOv8

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, yolov8

I tried to create a training.py to run yolov8 on my computer but in the end it shows me this error:

**The code:**

````
```from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch

# Create a new YOLO model from scratch
model = YOLO('yolov8s.yaml')

# Load a pretrained YOLO model (recommended for training)
#model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

# Train the model using the 'coco128.yaml' dataset for 3 epochs
results = model.train(data='D:/master_yolo/ultralytics/datasets/data.yaml', epochs=3)```
````

**And the error is shown as below:**

````
```
  File "c:\python\py39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```
````

I tried to put this line below in the code above, but it still didn't work:

```
def run():
    torch.multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    print('loop')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Can you try putting the `freeze_support` call directly in the `if __name__ == "__main__` block? Could you also try to use the `freeze_support` from the `multiprocessing` package instead?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and i solved it by thi

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch

# Use the model
if __name__ == '__main__':      
    results = model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=50)  # train the model
```